# Default values not working when used with static URL Segments in routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My routing configuration is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "public{controller}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
```

When I browse with http://localhost:59044/publicAdmin. It works fine

But when I browse with http://localhost:59044/public. It's not taking default value for Controller and Action, it's throwing me error saying that resource not found.

Comment: Since its a custom route, controller needs to be provided. Only for default route, you don't need to specify controller and action

Answer (score 0):

Add one more route before NewRoute route:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultNewRoute", "public",
new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
```

Comment: i have already provided default value in my routing i.e routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "public{controller}/{action}",
new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" }).So it should take default value when i browse http://localhost:59044/public.It should browse http://localhost:59044/public/Home/Index by using default value

Comment: Since you have public keyword in the route, only providing /public will throw error. So, for this case, add the above 1 more route so that when you specify /public, it invokes index view

Comment: Can u please explain below routing configuration what it is doing      routes.MapRoute("DefaultNewRoute", "public",
new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });

Comment: when your url matches http://localhost:59044/public, then your Index action of Home controller is called. That is what you require right.

Comment: ok which ever url starts with public this above routing configuration will get match as per your words.but this configuration should also match this route right ....routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "public{controller}/{action}",
     new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });

Comment: Not starts with public, if the url has /public only* , if you add the above route as i have mentioned in the ans. if the url has /public{controllername} or /public{controllername}/{action} , then your added map route will work

Comment: ok i got it now...but why mvc routing is not mapping for routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "public{controller}/{action}",
     new { controller = "Home", Action = "Index" }),If i browse ~/public ,it should take default value for controller and action as specfied as default values

Comment: That is how routing is designed in mvc. The reason is that suppose you have one more routemap with only "public" as the url string, then it will be a conflict. ie. if you have this mapping -  routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "public",
            new { controller = "Home", Action = "About" }); Then there will be issue. So, that is why its not allowed.

Comment: Did you try out the answer?